# Updating modal popup (facebox) with ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make a sign in page (in rails 3) where a modal dialog pops up (facebox) when the user clicks on a "sign in" link. I have everything working without ajax and without the modal pop up.

I'm trying to implement this by doing the following:

1. Show modal pop up containing a sign in form when user clicks "sign in"
2. Perform ajax post in rails via (remote: => true)

   1. If credentials are good, login user and redirect to home page
   2. if credentials are bad, show the flash message and reset the sign in form modal pop up

The part I'm stuck on is the very last part, showing the flash message and resetting the sign in page in the model pop up.

How do I do this last step?

**Edit:**

I understand from the comments that I need to send the flash message as json to my view and I know how to do that (json response in the controller). But how do I wire things up so I can show the flash message and reset the form in the modal without reloading the whole page?

Comment: you can't have flash + ajax because flash are stored in session, send your errors in json to your view.

Comment: ok thanks for that. but how do i reload the modal popup with the form reset? do i just have to reload the page and programmatically fire the modal popup? there must be a better way.

Comment: Maybe you can use https://github.com/ihower/facebox_render, I think it does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Francisco thanks for the link. I'll definitely check that out. But I also want to know how to do this manually. That's part of how to learn right? :)

Comment: You're welcome! And for sure... but take a quick look at the plugins code and you'll learn how to do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are submitting form through Ajax (:remote => true) then you can send the JavaScript response from the server on validation fails. This response will display the error messages.
If you have any further query then go ahead :)

Comment: Will the javascript response automatically reload in the modal popup that it was sent from? If so, then I guess I don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Actually facebox is a part of that HTML page not like normal popups(child window). So i don't think u need to do anything else.